# Facebook What is a Channel File?

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth, initialization

As the title states, my question is what is a channel file.

I am creating an Javascript program that connects to the user's Facebook account using OAuth.

There is an initialization script that looks as such

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
// Additional JS functions here
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

// Additional init code here

};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));
</script>
```

So in the channelUrl what would I set that to? What does it mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a side note, channel is no longer used: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27262105/474597

Answer (score 3):

You can find a description of the channel URL parameter below.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/

It goes into detail on why you would want want to include the parameter, but below is really the most important part.

> Asynchronous loading is another simple tactic that allows your page to load quickly without blocking the loading of other elements of your page.

Comment: Does the channel url html file have to be called channel.html?

Comment: Nope, only requirement is it has to be a fully qualified public URL that can be accessed by Facebook.

Comment: the channelfile is not mentioned anymore in the current docs, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart#loading does anybody know why? is it not needed anymore? maybe it was only for real old IEs like 6 and 7 and there are not supported anyways anymore?