# Is channelUrl parameter for Facebook init() deprecated?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I remember that there was a channelUrl option for `FB.init()`, but it seems that it does not exist anymore according to [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/)

Is this feature deprecated?

Comment: Yes it is not used anymore

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, channelUrl is no longer required.  Here's a quote from the blog post:

> **Changed browser requirements for the JavaScript SDK**
>
> In order for the JavaScript SDK to be able to communicate with Facebook, we now require either native support for HTML5 postMessage, or support for Flash, minimum version 8.0.24. As part of this change, we are no longer supporting the use of the channelUrl initialization option to provide a fallback mechanism.

Source: [Facebook Blog, Nov 2013](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/11/21/platform-updates--new-design-for-follow-button-and-like-box--ios-sdk-improvements-and-more/)