# Ui.Router Resolve Window.FB after FB Init

Tags: angularjs, facebook

**Question**
Hi I want my stateProvider to wait until Facebook is initialized. Then it should assign the `$window.FB` var to my controller.

**I took this approach as an orientation:**
[How to detect when facebook's FB.init is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548493/how-to-detect-when-facebooks-fb-init-is-complete)

**App.js**

```
module.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider' ,function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('share',{
      url:'/share',
      templateUrl:'modules/Share/Share.html',
      controller: 'ShareCtrl',
      controllerAs:'shareCtrl',
      data: {
        auth: "LoggedIn"
      },
      resolve: {
        FB: ['$window', function($window){
          return $window.FB.getUserID(function(response){
            return 'test';
            // return $window.FB;
          });     
        }]
      }
    });
}]);
```

...

```
module.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'authUserService', '$FB', function($rootScope, $state, authUserService, $FB) {
  $FB.init('475092975961783', './Modules/Social/FB-Channel.html');

}]);
```

My Facebook Init functions is basically the same as here:
https://github.com/djds4rce/angular-socialshare/blob/master/angular-socialshare.js
Besides that I pass an url for the channel.html (which I think is not even required anymore, [Is channelUrl parameter for Facebook init() deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261080/is-channelurl-parameter-for-facebook-init-deprecated)).

**Controller**

```
module.controller('ShareCtrl', ['$scope', 'myFacebookService', 'FB', function($scope, myFacebookService, FB) {
    this.rootUrl = 'modules/Share/';
     console.log(FB);
     // console.log(myFacebookService.getUser(FB));
}]);
```

The variable never gets resolved and the view never gets loaded. `window.FB.getUserID()` in the browser console returns me my FacebookAppID.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to modify the library and add a promise. When it is resolved the object gets loaded.:

```
angular.module('af.angular-socialshare', [])
.factory('$FB',['$window', '$q', function($window, $q){
  // data stored here exists only once per app
  var loaded = $q.defer();

  return {
    init: function(fbId, channelUrl){
      if(fbId){
        this.fbId = fbId;
        $window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId: fbId,
            channelUrl: channelUrl,
            status: true,
            xfbml: true
          });
          loaded.resolve($window.FB);
        };
        (function(d){
          var js,
          id = 'facebook-jssdk',
          ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
          }

          js = d.createElement('script');
          js.id = id;
          js.async = true;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";

          ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);

        }(document));
      }
      else{
        throw("FB App Id Cannot be blank");
      }
    },
    getFB: function(){
      return loaded.promise;
    }

  };

}])
```

And then resolve the FB Object

```
$stateProvider
    .state('share',{
      url:'/share',
      templateUrl:'modules/Share/Share.html',
      controller: 'ShareCtrl',
      controllerAs:'shareCtrl',
      data: {
        auth: "LoggedIn"
      }
      ,
      resolve: {
        FB: ['$FB', function($FB){
          return $FB.getFB();
        }]
      }
    });
```